# Retrieve parent-child hierarchy from a self-referencing table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, parent-child, tree-structure

I had a elements hierarchy above structure. 
[image: Hierarchy structure]

In this hierarchy of the elements insert into the my db like below image.
[image: table structure]

- In this table elements are having separate elementid and label of the element.
- Connectors will connect the two elements and that's having the separate id and start point is source and end point is target.
- The source and target points are having the elementid which is connected to start and end point.

> I will get the data from the above mentioned table and inserted into the elementmapping table. As like below mentioned table.

[image]

***Note:*** *The hierarchy of the elements level dynamically increasing at any level.*

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I am using  version of MySQL is 5.5.5-10.1.38-MariaDB. @Rwd

Comment: In that case I would suggest looking at https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset

Comment: A nested set does not seem to be an option if a child can have two parents (as with id 12). I'd suggest a look at [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20215744), which is a pretty much complete overview of what you can do. Pick some code or different data model that fits your requirements (MySQL < 8, unlimited depths, ...), try to implement it, ask (with the code you tried) if you run into troubles (which you probably will). Just to emphasize: without MySQL 8, you most likely have to live with some restrictions, pick those that don't matter for you.